# MacBook Pro Retina thinks internal display is LG TV inside ColorSync utility

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, display, color

So, about a month ago, my MacBook Pro Retina 13" (Late 2013) display died. When I went to an authorized service provider, they tested it out and said that it needed to be replaced (the display). They said that it would take a week before the display was shipped to them, and in the meantime, I could use my MacBook Pro on an external display.

A year before this (around April 2015), my display had died, but it revived itself overnight somehow. I used it on my external LG TV, and after it revived itself, it used "HD-709 A as the default color profile, and even if I changed it back to "Color LCD", the HD-709 A would stay on the login screen.

Now, I went home after seeing the service provider and used the TV as my external display. After I got my computer back from replacing the display, I saw that the same thing had occured. I dug a little deeper into ColorSync utility, and now, the main display is called "LG TV", even though it is on the internal display, in systeminformation, it shows a built in retina display (but in ColorSync utility, it says LG TV is default, and the internal Retina one doesnt even show up, and the default profile for my computer is again HD-709 A.

In System Preferences, however, it is called "Built-In Retina Display". I can still use Color LCD, but the TV's main profile is stuck to the computer for now. When it happened the first time, a reformat fixed it. Is there a way to make ColorSync utility recognize that my internal display is default and completely remove the external one?

[image: inside colorsync utility > devices]
Inside ColorSync
[image: SystemPrefs>Display]
Inside SysPrefs

Comment: Also, a side question, when this same MacBook Pro heats up and has intensive GPU use, it makes a clicking sound. No graphics performance is reduced, and the Display works fine, just the color problems

Comment: Is that clicking a fan not working?

Comment: No, its not a clicking clicking sound, more like a tick sound. I also checked the fan (only one in this model) under load, and its RPM is just fine

Comment: @Dubstep_cats Did you try a PRAM reset, sometimes it could reset a display problems like this. Also did you try to repair the profiles from Profile First Aid from ColorSync Utility?

Comment: Yes, a PRAM and SMC reset, and I also verified the profiles. Nothing wrong. In the color sync utility, LG TV only shows up under displays and is marked as default.

Comment: It might be a preference file somewhere, I just went to a time machine backup that I made before this incident, and restored the /Library/ColorSync/Profiles/Displays Folder and no avail